# What is the recommended way to close a Preferences screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, preference

Android beginner here...

I'm working through various examples, setting up a preferences screen. But the part I don;t understand is how the user is expected to exit the screen

```
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
     ...
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@android:color/white">


<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/dialog_based_preferences">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title_edittext_preference"
        android:key="edittext_preference"
        android:summary="@string/summary_edittext_preference"
        android:title="@string/title_edittext_preference" />

    <ListPreference
        android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title_list_preference"
        android:entries="@array/entries_list_preference"
        android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_list_preference"
        android:key="list_preference"
        android:summary="@string/summary_list_preference"
        android:title="@string/title_list_preference" />

 </PreferenceCategory>
```

But the guide I cannot seem to find is how the user is expected to CLOSE the preferences screen? What is the "official guidance" on this?

One example I've come across is to have a button on the preferences screen to exit. But it get the impression that its a non-standard approach (if there is such a thing).

Is this really the best way of closing the screen?

```
 <Preference
    android:key="@string/SavePref"
    android:title="SAVE AND EXIT"
    android:summary="Click > 
    android:widgetLayout="@layout/pref_reset_bd_button">
 </Preference>
```

Or is it supposed to be dealt with in the app toolbar with a <- arrow. I've certainly seen both types in the various apps I myself use.

Just wondering what the "advice" is, if there is any. 
Cheers.

Comment: This depends on how you use the fragment. If you use this fragment alongside other fragments in the same activity, you can manipulate the onBackPressed (inside the activity) to go back to the previous fragment. If you use it as a single fragment inside an activity you should just use the <- arrow. Note that that actually kills the activity this fragment resides in, cleaning up is done automaticly through the destroyView and onDestroy.

Comment: Well, it's a simple preferences screen. So I'm thinking it's just one fragment, in the MainActivity.But killing the MainActivitywhile trying to exit the preferences fragment is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

The user is expected to close it by pressing the back button or by providing up navigation (the arrow at the upper left corner of the screen).

**Back Button**

Here is how the define the back button :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (SOMETHING) {
    DO SOMETHING ELSE
    return;
}

// Otherwise defer to system default behavior.
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The default behavior is to get back to the top activity of the stack once this one is popped.

**Providing up navigation**

You can also set the preference's parent activity this way :

```
<application ... >
...
<!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
    ...
</activity>

<!-- A child of the main activity -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
</application>
```

So the action bar will allow the user to get back to the activity you wish to.

Comment: "So the action bar will allow the user to get back to the activity you wish to" - exactly what I'm looking for! The problem is that whilst I can add the "up navigation" on the main activity, my preferences fragment is full screen, covering everything.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like this (since you said you had an activity and a fragment)

in your xml:

```
<Preference
android:id="@+id/mPreferenceId"
android:key="@string/SavePref"
android:title="SAVE AND EXIT"
android:summary="Click > 
android:widgetLayout="@layout/pref_reset_bd_button">
</Preference>
```

In your activity get the view by id and add something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mPreference.getVisibility() != View.GONE){
        ((ViewGroup)mPreference.getParent()).removeView(mPreference);
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

If you have no further reference it should automaticly destroy the view.

If by fullscreen you mean you dont have the bottom buttons, then add a callback listener and implement that if statement there.